# Scraping Google Play Store BeautifulSoup / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, google-play

I'm scraping data from the Android Store (Google Play Store) and I want to automate the downloading process on a connected phone. I'm trying to automate the click on the 'Install' button in an app page with Selenium but I can't click on it

Here is my python code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
             id=com.playdemic.golf.android")


dr_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fcxH9b']/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/c-wiz[1]/c-wiz[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/span/button")
dr_button.click()
```

Comment: Does anything happen at all? Do you get an error message? Can you put a `print(dr_button)` just before the last shown line and show us what the result is?

Comment: @mypetlion Nothing happens. Here is the result of the print(dr_button) :
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="FF2CFC32-8038-4A0B-9A37-EA6958357A02", element="node-1CDDCAA3-86FC-4868-BC24-9C6CEA5EE273")>

Comment: parsing google is very hard i think

Comment: Are you sure the `driver` is getting your expected page view? Perhaps the install button was not available in the page.  This seems especially likely on the Play Store as the Install button can be dynamic based on pricing and region.  Or perhaps upon clicking it prompts you to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Google uses element obfuscation to prevent automation against their site in a malicious manner. You are on the right path with using XPATH, but you're going to have to manually create the XPATH... path.. which will help simplify your code, anyway. You could so something such as:

```
dr_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Install']")
```

EDIT: To clarify on element obfuscation, you can see all the class names, as well as other element attributes are a seemingly random 6 character alpha numeric string. These strings can and will change intermittently. Most element-finding is used my element `id`'s and `class`es.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

I solved 90% of the problem with Safari, I had first to log in here is my code.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
id=com.king.candycrushsaga")

connexionbutton= "//*[@id='gb_70']"
emailfield= "identifierId"
GoogleAccUser="*****@gmail.com"
GoogleAccPassword="*****"
passwordfield="//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"
nextButton = "//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span"
nextButtonTwo = "//*[@id='passwordNext']/content/span"
appsTabW  = "//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span/span[2]"
appsTab = "//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a"
installButton = "//*[@id='fcxH9b']/div[4]/c- 
wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/c-wiz[1]/c- 
wiz[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/span/button"
confirmInstallButton = "//*[@id='purchase-ok-button']/span"
xx = "//*[@id='purchase-cancel-button']"



loginbuttonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathbutton))
loginbuttonElement.click()

emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_id(emailfield))
emailFieldElement.clear()
emailFieldElement.send_keys(GoogleAccUser)

nextButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextButton))
nextButtonElement.click()

passwordFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(passwordfield))
passwordFieldElement.clear()
passwordFieldElement.send_keys(GoogleAccPassword)

nextButtonElementTwo = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextButtonTwo))
nextButtonElementTwo.click()

 installButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: 
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(installButton))
 installButtonElement.click()

confirmInstallButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(lambda 
 driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(xx))
 confirmInstallButtonElement.click()
```

Now the problem is the Install confirmation which is on a popup window and I can't detect the button to click on it and download the app

Answer (score 0):

I have to log in, but i can click on "install"! :) Try other browser?
[image: RESULT FOR:]

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playdemic.golf.android")


dr_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fcxH9b']/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/c-wiz[1]/c-wiz[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/span/button")
dr_button.click()
```